# Why do I get two types of hover effects in my navbar?

Tags: css, hover, border, navbar

Why do I get two types of animation effects when I hover over my navbar items? First it shows rectangular background then it becomes circular (which I want)

```
<div class="container">
       <a href="https://www.google.com/"><div class="items" id="item-1">Home </div></a>


.items {
    padding-inline:20px ;
    padding-block: 10px;
    font-size: larger;
    margin-inline: 35px;
}

a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration:none ;
}


#item-1:hover {
    background-color: rgb(3, 151, 3);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: 0.15s;
    cursor:pointer ;    
}
```

Comment: One of them is the :hover effect on the parent `<a>`; the other the :hover affect on the child (`#item-1`).

Comment: another question: why do you need a div inside the "a" tag? you can use span instead

Comment: You haven't got 'two types of hover' - just the one going from the rectangular item-1 (the default border radius of 0) to the border with radius.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `#item-1` by default doesn't have `border-radius`, so when you hover it, it starts to apply `border-radius` and since you have set `transition: 0.15s;`, so this transition will apply to change all styles. to solve it you can set `border-radius` for `#item-1` by default and with hover effect just changing it's background like this:

```css
.items {
  padding-inline: 20px;
  padding-block: 10px;
  font-size: larger;
  margin-inline: 35px;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#item-1 {
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 0.15s;
}

#item-1:hover {
  background-color: rgb(3, 151, 3);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/">
    <div class="items" id="item-1">Home </div>
  </a>
```